# how make crystal report faster in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Hi i working on windows form application

I have created one crystal report . i have code in my button click like this:

```
SqlCommand cmdrslt = new SqlCommand("Staffwiserpt", con.connect);
cmdrslt.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdrslt.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = frmdateval;
cmdrslt.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = Todateval;
cmdrslt.Parameters.Add("@deptid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = deptid;
cmdrslt.Parameters.Add("@empid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = empid;
da.SelectCommand = cmdrslt;
da.Fill(ds);
Staffwisecrpt rpt = new Staffwisecrpt();
if ((ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0)) {
    rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0));
    rpt.SetParameterValue("frmd", setparmstartd);
    rpt.SetParameterValue("tod", setparmendd);
    rpt.SetParameterValue("Dept", cmbdepartment.Text);
    rpt.SetParameterValue("Employename", cmbemployee.Text);

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
} 
else {
    MessageBox.show("No Records found", MsgBoxStyle.Information);
    return;
}
```

but this is taking some time to show the crystal report..is there any other way to write this code for improving my crystal report performance..?
how about **background worker**?? i can implement that to this code?
any help is very appreciable?

Comment: http://www.studyoverflow.org/2013/06/crystal-report-in-c-windows-application.html

Comment: i used to do this way..but this taking some time to show the result in crystal report?

Comment: (1) identify the bottlenecks, what (chunk of) code specifically takes a long time. (2) Find out why it is a bottleneck. If you can't find a solution: (3) use StackOverflow, i.e. rephrase this question.

Comment: only this much code i am using? if i use back ground worker that will affect performance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use background worker, take a look at this [LINK](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/88605-the-background-worker/) .

but the best thing is you must optimize your code or query before displaying it to crystal report.

**UPDATE**

[LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029431/vb-net-crystal-report-takes-time-to-load)

Comment: sir could you please show example code formate ,how to implement background worker code to this code?

Comment: sir,,so what i have to edit in my code ,,please advic me